# kibana dont start up on linux machine

Tags: kibana-7

I am getting below error while starting kibana from linux box. Kibana version I am using is 7.3.1

./kibana: syntax error at line 6: `ls=$' unexpected

Please suggest and let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime moving to next more stable version may solve the problem.